"Constant expression required" error in Android Studio
`I am trying to make a calculator in android studio but facing the issue in the java file I tried a lot but still facing the "Constant expression required" error
        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.btnClear:
                // Clear the display
                displayEditText.setText("0");
                break;
            case R.id.btnSign:
                // Toggle between positive and negative signs
                String currentText = displayEditText.getText().toString();
                if (!currentText.isEmpty() && !currentText.equals("0")) {
                    if (currentText.charAt(0) == '-') {
                        displayEditText.setText(currentText.substring(1));
                    } else {
                        displayEditText.setText("-" + currentText);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case R.id.btnPercent:
                // Handle percent button (placeholder logic)
                // For example, if you want to add 10% to the current value, you can do:
                double currentValue = Double.parseDouble(displayEditText.getText().toString());
                double newValue = currentValue * 1.1; // Adding 10%
                displayEditText.setText(String.valueOf(newValue));
                break;
            case R.id.btnDivide:
                // Handle divide button (placeholder logic)
                // For example, if you want to divide the current value by 2, you can do:
                double valueToDivide = Double.parseDouble(displayEditText.getText().toString());
                if (valueToDivide != 0) {
                    double result = valueToDivide / 2;
                    displayEditText.setText(String.valueOf(result));
                } else {
                    displayEditText.setText("Error"); // Division by zero
                }
                break;
            // Handle other buttons similarly
            default:
                // Handle num`your text`ber and operator buttons
                Button button = (Button) v;
                String buttonText = button.getText().toString();
                String currentDisplay = displayEditText.getText().toString();
                if (currentDisplay.equals("0")) {
                    displayEditText.setText(buttonText);
                } else {
                    displayEditText.append(buttonText);
                }
                break;
        }

I  tried to add bracket and semicolon in switch case part but not worked`
